# Optimize insert and update query

Tags: mysql

How to optimize my insert and update query..

Update Query:

```
UPDATE `cp_sessions` 
    SET `last_activity` = 1389937578, 
        `user_id` = NULL, 
        `user_data` = 'a:3:{s:9:\"game_name\";s:5:\"poker\";s:3:\"utm\";N;s:5:\"url_1\";s:23:\"http://adda52merge.org/\";}' 
    WHERE `session_id` = '52b4aae2432db5c8236523e5357fb48d';
```

Insert Query:

```
INSERT INTO `cp_sessions` 
     (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`)
VALUES (
    'a68ca9a8d4b4f9462b4439bc60d05e91', 
    '192.168.1.235', 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko', 1389937583);
```

It will take Query_time: 1.654473

Comment: what tables are you using Innodb, myisam ? What is the table size ? How many writes are there per second/min/hour ? What is the primary key of the table ? session_id ? are there any indexes defined ?

Comment: Hi,table name== innodb,table size==.02mb,time in second,no primary key and index.. so please tell me how can i optimize my query both inser and update condition..

Answer (score 1):

If your table has no primary key, add it.
If you have a session_id primary key, it will be unique, there will not be two records using the same session_id value.

```
ALTER TABLE `cp_sessions`
CHANGE COLUMN `session_id` `session_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`);
```

If you have duplicate session_id values, then clear them like

```
    CREATE TABLE blah LIKE cp_sessions;
    ALTER TABLE `blah` CHANGE COLUMN `session_id` `session_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO blah SELECT * FROM cp_sessions;
    RENAME TABLE cp_sessions TO cp_session_old, blah TO cp_sessions;
```

This way you can either keep doing what you are doing, 
or you can have a single query, without executing the update separately.

```
INSERT INTO `cp_sessions` 
     (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`)
VALUES (
    'a68ca9a8d4b4f9462b4439bc60d05e91', 
    '192.168.1.235', 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko', 1389937583)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_activity = VALUES(last_activity), user_agent = VALUES(user_agent);
```